# Which fetch mode I should use to read a single column value

Tags: php, sql, pdo

All right, I am trying to develop a program, what you need to know:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT NationID FROM Users WHERE UserEmail = '{email here}' AND 'NationPassword' = '{password here}'");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result
```

The big problem with this is that the table has the following:

> "NationID":"8"
>  "NationName":"Kharim"
>  "UserEmail":"{email here}"
>   "NationPassword":"{password here}"
>  "NationLocation":"Africa"

But I just want NationID, how do I go about this. (Another error, that I assume would be fixed by someone explaining this, is that currently echo $result literally just returns "1". SO if someone could explain to me how to read just specific parts of this, not the whole table - and make $result not return just "1" would be amazing. Thank you.*
Side note: Just so you don't assume this is an error, {email here} and {password here} both stand for real information that I would like to keep hidden.*

Comment: you've just set the fetch mode, but you haven't done the actual fetching of rows yet `->fetch()`

Comment: you just get the `1` since `->setFetchMode()` returns `true / false`, and in your case you `echo`ed it that's why you see the `1` there

Comment: So what do I do then?

Comment: alternatively, you can just use `->fetchColumn()`, it returns the `NationID`, but if you want the whole rowset, use `->fetch()`

Comment: also remember to use prepared statements properly, don't directly inject your variables into the actual statement, use `?` placeholders in your statement and load all your values into `->execute([email here, password here])`. don't save plain passwords too :)

Comment: So would I use ```fetchColumn(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)``` instead of ```setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);```?

Comment: no just use `->fetchColumn()` no need for arguments

Comment: I just changed -setFetchMode() to fetchColumn(), nothing else and now the page generates a 500 error.

Comment: im not sure what you're doing right now, just follow the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) you can check out how to use it, and here's the entry for [setFetchMode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) so you can understand their distinction and use

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setFetchMode() and fetchColumn() you can try like below.

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT `NationID` 
    FROM `Users` 
    WHERE `UserEmail`:=email 
    AND `NationPassword`=:password
");

// Assign the values to the placeholder
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email); 
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();

// Fetch possible result and return it as array
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Check if we have a result and print out
if (!$result) {
    echo $result['NationID'];
} else {
    echo "No related entry";
```

1. Use backticks (`) instead of single quotes for table/column names.
2. When you use prepared statements, then don't pass the values directly in the query, pass it via the methods `bindValue()` or `bindParam()`.

Comment: what's wrong with fetchColumn()?

Comment: there is no need for rowCount()

Comment: @Dharman 1. I changed to `$stmt->rowCount()`. The reson to check here is, that the query can also return nothing and in this case `$result['NationID'] would not exists He can also check with `if (!$result)`. 2. Thanks, the = was not the only missing, I also missed 1 $ before.

Comment: I mean yes, I am happy. It's quite a good example. Logically I think you have the condition reversed, but other than that the code looks good to me. Of course OP should never store plaintext passwords in the database, but that is a separate point.